# Intellij : Configure Label Decorations for Git and Subversion

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-13, intellij-15

I recently switched to `Intellij` and i want to know if there is a possibility to display `git` or `svn` informations (author name, last commit date ...) associated to a given project file, like `Eclipse` do :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide an example of what do you wanna to achieve? Screenshot from another program with them or so. From your description I can't understand clearly, what do you want exactly, but as I know IDEA didn't have such things out of box.

Comment: i've added a screenshot, hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no label decoration through hovering on the file, but you can do:

Right-click on the file --> `Git` --> `Show Current Revision`

This will show you the commit hash, modified by, date, and commit message.

[image]

Working in Idea 14.